# Manipulation of date in VB

Tags: oracle, vb6

How can we extract system time in VB and perform calculations, i.e. adding or subtracting time then store change time in  oracle database table in earlier format?

Answer (score 4):

To get the system time

```
Dim timestamp As Date: timestamp = Now
timestamp = timestamp - Int(timestamp)
```

To add or subtract a time interval (e.g. add one hour)

```
timestamp = DateAdd("h", 1, timestamp)
```

To store it in a database, something like

```
Dim cnn As New Connection
cnn.ConnectionString = "YourConnectionString"

Dim cmd As New Command
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = "YourStoredProcName"
cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn

Dim prm As Parameter: Set prm = cmd.CreateParameter("YourParameterName", adDBTime, adParamInput)
prm.Value = timestamp

Call cmd.Parameters.Append(prm)
Call cnn.Open
Call cmd.Execute
Call cnn.Close
```